# To have strict and warnings in Perl oneliner

Tags: perl, testing

I really miss `use strict; use warnings` in my Perl one-liners such as:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /[0-5],[0-5]?|hernia|.{170,}|benz/' file`
```

especially when I include many conditions separated by `|`.
I have noticed that the filtering becomes more and more unstable when you have more conditions.

Examples of data missed or where the command works unstably

```
123.Symptoms of hernia are all, except: | happy | energetic | sleeping | down regulation of CNS hello | running 5
Signshello of mercedes benz car model: | Big tyres | Even bigger roller | Massive emergency of try | Hello world | All from above 1
```

where two entries where the regex works unstably.

How can you use strict and warnings in Perl one-liners? 
How can you design such long conditional statements better?

Comment: Curious to understand why you think that `use strict` or `use warnings` would improve an N-way regular expression, and also why you think it becomes more unstable as complexity increases...?

Comment: @roaima Because I do not understand how to make more stable N-way regex. It seems to omit searches sometimes. More stable approach for this regex?

Comment: Please provide an example of an RE and data that it misses.

Comment: Try `perl -Mstrict -W`

Comment: Really!?  It's "unstable" when you have 51 conditions (simple sub-expressions), but, when you delete *any one* (leaving you with 50), it becomes "stable"?  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want strict and warnings, the answer is 'don't do a one liner'. Almost invariably one liners suffer from perl's propensity for write-only code.

Expand it out into a multi-liner instead. If you really want - you can embed it using a HEREDOC

```
 perl <<ENDPERL
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 print "This is a test\n";
 ENDPERL
```

Or alternatively:

```
perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -e 'print something'
```

But really - this won't help you debug that regular expression, since it's quite unlikely that the RE is going to be triggering warnings.

For longer conditionals, I go for the expedient route - write it down, that way you don't have to worry about missing something out the next time you use it. Your example looks like a 'simple' grep -v type construct:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @patterns_to_skip = ( "hernia", 
                          "ignshello", );

my $regex = join ( "|", map { quotemeta } @patterns_to_skip );
$regex = qr/$regex/;

while ( <> ) {
   print unless m/$regex/;
}
```

Comment: If going the multiline route, there's always `//x` to allow spaced and commented expressions within a complex but static RE.

Comment: I love the elegance of your while loop!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> perl -ne 'print unless /hernia|ignshello|...|n/' file
> ```

Your RE as provided will match any line of three of more characters (the `...`) or any line containing the letter `n`. I assume these aren't intentional, but may be why you consider it "unstable".

Since you haven't got any variables present in this one-liner, the `use warnings` and `use strict` would be of little help.

Comment: I don’t know about the `n`, but I betcha five zorkmids that, by `...`, the OP meant an ellipsis (`…`), meaning “there are many more here like the ones I have listed.”

Comment: @G-Man, I'm not accepting that bet. However, I asked the OP for an example of an RE and the data it misses, and that is what was given.

Comment: @Masi please [edit] your question to include this information. And also provide examples of lines where this RE is not doing what you expect.

Comment: @roaima: You’ve given the OP a link to edit *your answer* rather than his question.

Comment: @Masi: Please [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/209774/edit) (click here, or just use the [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/209774/edit) link under the question) to include a command that fails, including the *full* regex.  Don’t include `...` unless three-dots is *literally* part of the regex.  (And, while I said *full*, I absolutely encourage you to remove one component — preferably one of the longer ones (e.g., `|Choledochoduodenoa nastomosis`) — from your regex and try it again.  If it still fails, repeat until it works correctly;  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  then go back to the last one that failed, and do the same thing, shortening the search strings (e.g., `eimonectomy` → `eimo`) as far as you can without changing the outcome.)  Then, provide some sample input (I guess you’ve already done that, but this time, do the same thing I just described — make it shorter, as much as you can without making the “problem” go away.  Ideally, the text should fit in the text area without scrolling.)  Finally, show us the output of that command on that input data, and state what you expect the output to be (i.e., explain why you think it’s wrong).

Comment: I did the corrections but will add actual example outputs tomorrow. Generally speaking, I am interested in reasons why regex can become unstably with long options and many OR operators. Probably, a for-loop for a list of terms, and running exclusively regex each time singly could be better approach. Computational complexity is the apparent topic here.